# Using a listrenderer and check boxes in lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I've created the following custom list renderer for lwuit. The renderer extends a checkbox but for some reason, the select and unselect (check/uncheck) functions dont work.
If i `setselected()` all the items come selected and cant be unselected. 
Heres the sample code;

```
class TaskListRenderer extends CheckBox implements ListCellRenderer {

        public TaskListRenderer() {
            super();
        }

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object o, int i, boolean bln) {

            Tasks task = (Tasks) o;
            try {
                img = Image.createImage("/three.png");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
//            
            setIcon(img);
            setText(task.getPhoneID() + " " + task.getDate());

            Style style = new Style();//(0xff0000, 0x00ff00, null, byte(128));
            style.setBgColor(0xff0000);
            style.setFgColor(0x00ff00);
            setSelectedStyle(style);
            return this;
        }

        public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
            return this;
//            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi The line of code you are missing is

```
Tasks task = (Tasks) o;
setSelected(task.isSelect());
```

See a [working version](http://lumbungilmu.com/?p=271) hope this helps.

On a side note I highly recommend you move the code below to out side of the  getListCellRendererComponent because it gets called many many times when displaying a list and will slow down the performance of your app.

```
img = Image.createImage("/three.png");
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it out..works nicely. It involved some minor modification to my Tasks class.